# Don't Summarize Option Problem In Power BI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-modeling

I have 4 Columns, First is Date type which will be Axis Value (X- Axis), 3 **Decimal Type Value** (Values Field) which will represent as Line Chart i.e. 3 Lines inside the chart.

Problem?
When I drag and drop the Decimal Type Value inside the Values Field in Line Chart, it takes as SUM.
I already selected Don't Summarize in  Column tools tab with Uncategorised as Data Category.
The problem is when I click the down arrow in the Values Field, it doesn't shows "Don't Summarize" Option.
Now I need my data as it is, no sum no count, nothing.

How Can I achieve that?

Comment: Please include screenshots so we understand your problem better.

Comment: in the "Value" section of the line chart, you can't use data "as is" it must use an aggregation function. if you need it "as is" use a table visual or ensure that even if aggregated it returns the value itself.

Comment: Yes, @GiovanniLuisotto, Thank You. So, if I choose AVG as aggregate the value are as per my need. Other Aggregate function are not providing same results.

Comment: @soumyarjpanda Did it solve your problem actually? I also bumped to this at wasnt sure why in AVG/MIN/MAX aggr. I am having my "real" values...and if I change on SUMMARIZATION in Column Tools then it is applied depending what I wanna...

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto  Meaning, I can put AVG/MIN/MAX whatever to have my "real" values...kinda confusing when someone is looking at it....

Answer (score 0):

There is chance to duplicating the values so you might get more value than the present value. So have to create new table using below DAX then apply to you visual.

```
DISTINCT(SUMMARIZE(ResellerSales_USD  
      , DateTime[CalendarYear]  
      , "Sales Amount (USD)", SUM(ResellerSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD])  
      )
```